# Don't know where is database that was created using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I was following a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj193542.aspx) and created a database using code first. But now I'd like to remove the database, but I can't find where it is.

I don't have SQL Server installed. I am using VS2013 community edition.

I've looked at my [`app.config`](http://pastebin.com/SA6iCYGQ) file, my [main code](http://pastebin.com/dtjqUk0n) and the [SQL Server Object Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuRLF.jpg) pane but I still can't figure it out.

Any help to find and delete this database would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm going to answer my own question since I've found the database.

First thing I did was [add a connection to the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1boE.jpg). I did this by going to the "Server Explorer" pane, clicked on "Connect to a database", chose MS SQL Server, typed in ".\SQLEXPRESS" in the servername dropdown box, then I was able to choose my database from the database name field.

The second thing that I did was click on the ["SQL server object explorer" pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TByG6.jpg), the ./SQLEXPRESS server showed up (it wasn't there before), from there I could find and delete the database.